# PHP array data not updating

Tags: php, arrays, session

The assignment is to have a table display some products with an add to cart link which sends the user to another page which uses the information in the link to get the data to display the total of the purchase.  The table is adding in new items that are clicked but not updating the actual quantity when an item is clicked more than once.

I have tried placing an echo in the check for the item already being in the cart and it does state the quantity of 1 before the quantity update and 2 after the update but for some reason this is not actually updating.  The same goes for the price.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
      $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
  }

  $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

  $id = $_GET['productid'];
  $name = $_GET['productname'];
  $price = $_GET['productprice'];
  $qty = 1;
  $alreadyHas = 0;

  foreach($cart as $cartKey => $cartItem) {
      if(!empty($cartItem['pid'])) {
        if($cartItem['pid'] == $id) {
            $cartItem['qty'] = $cartItem['qty'] + 1;
            $cartItem['total'] = $cartItem['price'] * $cartItem['qty'];
            $alreadyHas = 1;
        }
      }
  }
  if($alreadyHas == 0) {
    $cartItem = array(
        'pid' => $id,
        'name' => $name,
        'price' => $price,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'total' => $price
      );
      array_push($cart, $cartItem);
  }

  $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in your `foreach` loop. You are updating `$cartitem` however because you are not passing it by reference in the loop the `$cart` variable itself is not being updated. Try changing the `foreach` loop to this (note the addition of `&` before `$cartItem):

```
foreach($cart as $cartKey => &$cartItem) {
```

Note that you could simplify your code with the use of [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
if (($k = array_search($id, array_column($cart, 'pid'))) !== false) {
    $cart[$k]['qty'] = $cart[$k]['qty'] + 1;
    $cart[$k]['total'] = $cart[$k]['price'] * $cart[$k]['qty'];
}
else {
    $cartItem = array(
        'pid' => $id,
        'name' => $name,
        'price' => $price,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'total' => $price
      );
      array_push($cart, $cartItem);
}
```

Comment: the other alternative syntax you can write `$cart[$cartKey]['qty'] = ...` for your assignment. Both equally valid.